# Dynamic new field in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is this possible to create `new {variable = x.something}` and specify variable name dynamically? For example:

```
var name = "dynamicName"; 
var result = context.select(x=> new {name.ToString() = x.something })
```

In this way we would have a list where property name is dynamicName.
So is this somehow possible?

Comment: you could use a `NameValueCollection` instead of your anonymous type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx

Comment: Why do you need something like this?

Comment: @Daniel for example to create column names dynamically

Comment: @ADrian entity framework

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with an anonymous type, because anonymous types are not dynamic. They must be completely defined at compile time. However, you could use a dynamic object like `ExpandoObject`:

```
var name = "dynamicName"; 
var result = context.Select(x =>
                            {
                                var exp = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                                exp[name] = x.something;
                                return (dynamic)exp;
                            });
```

Comment: interesting approach, I just wonder how you could possibly use `result` in a sensible manner now, as it could technically be a collection of literally anything. Just some food for thought....

Comment: “A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree”

Comment: @kosnkov, actually that would work with Linq to Objects, but I don't think there's a way to do that with Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

Use a

```
    Dictionary<string,string> myDic
```

Then

```
    myDic.Add(name.ToString(), x.something)
```

Comment: +1 but I'd suggest `Dictionary<string, object>` then. For the simple reason that `x.something` is not necessarily a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can create anonymous type at runtime with Reflection.Emit but it is not very easy (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec). Usually it is better just to us dictonary, array or dynamic